# Angular 2 / RxJS - subscribing breaks when http returns 400

Tags: angular, rxjs

The following code is to debounce an input, where a user would type and address and it would search after the user stops typing for 500ms:

```
    let debounce = this.search_terms.pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        map((term: string) => this.mapify_api.searchAddress(term))
    );

    debounce.subscribe(
        (data:any) => {

          console.log('request successful');

        },
        (data:any) => {

          console.log('request unsuccessful');

        }
    );
```

It works perfectly until the endpoint I'm calling returns a 400 which would result in the console logging 'request unsuccessful'. After this the subscription breaks and it no longer listens to the changing of the input. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Observable will complete if there's an error thrown in the stream. You will need to handle it and repeat the stream in order for it to resume.

```
  let debounce = this.search_terms.pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        map((term: string) => this.mapify_api.searchAddress(term)),
        catchError(e=>of(e)),
        first(),
        repeat()
    );
```